# How do I play a sound when an element changes, like SO Chat does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, mutation-events

I want a sound to play when an element changes on a page. I know how to do this, but I can't get it to play **only on the first change**, and don't do it later, until the user focuses the window (tab) and blurs it again.

**My current code:**

```
var notif = new Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');
if (window.innerHeight === window.outerHeight) {
  $(window).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
      notif.play();
  });
}
```

Comment: What you have shouldn't work, your object call to `.bind()` isn't complete...isn't that throwing a syntax error?

Comment: **Update:** I fixed the sound path, it was wrong. Please update your answers. I'll check both answers again later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to represent whether the sound should be played or not.

```
var shouldPlayAlertSound = true,
    notif = new Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');
if (window.innerHeight === window.outerHeight) {
  $(window).bind({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
      if (shouldPlayAlertSound) {
        notif.play();
      }
      shouldPlayAlertSound = false;
    }, blur: function() {
      shouldPlayAlertSound = true;
    } 
  });
}
```

**Edit:** I've [tested this working](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NKX2j/6/show/light/) on Firefox, Safari, and Opera (except for the innerHeight check). (Chrome doesn't support playing WAV audio files, only the MP3, AAC, or Ogg Vorbis formats.)

Comment: This code seems to be fine, and **jsLint** only shows up only one error: *Problem at line 6 character 48: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.* `shouldPlayAlertSound && notif.play();`. But even if I replace this with `if (shouldPlayAlertSound === true) { notif.play(); }`, it does not work. :/

Comment: **Thanks!** I've made minor fixes to your new code, and now it's doing exactly what I wanted! http://jsfiddle.net/Nyuszika7H/hpRHR/

Answer (score 0):

If this is your only `DOMNodeInserted` handler, I'd just remove it when the work is done (making all future insertions cheaper), like this:

```
notif = new Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');
if (window.innerHeight === window.outerHeight) {
  $(window).bind({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() { 
      notif.play(); 
      $(window).unbind('DOMNodeInserted'); 
    }
  });
}
```

If it's *not* the only handler that's workable too, just make it a named function:

```
notif = new Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');
if (window.innerHeight === window.outerHeight) {
  function play() { notif.play(); $(window).unbind('DOMNodeInserted', play); }
  $(window).bind({
    'DOMNodeInserted': play
  });
}
```